# Android canvas background colour doesn't match colour value

Tags: android, colors, android-canvas, surfaceview

I have created a pie chart SurfaceView component.  When I set the background colour to #fff0f0f0 the colour on the screen has a pink tinge to it.  When I take a screenshot of the image and load it into an paint package the hex colour value is f7f3f7.  I'm using the following code to clear the background;

```
int backgroundColour = getResources().getColor(R.color.grey);

Paint colour = new Paint();
colour.setAntiAlias(true);
colour.setColor(backgroundColour);

canvas.drawColor(colour.getColor());
```

This is called just after I call;

```
surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null)
```

I cannot figure out what is causing this problem.  The alpha channel is set to FF so there shouldn't be anything showing through from behind.

Just to note I have tried with and without the Alpha channel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For historical reasons, the default color format for a SurfaceView is RGB_565, which can lead to funky-looking greys (not to mention banding).

You can use the [SurfaceHolder#setFormat()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#setFormat(int)) call to change the color format to RGB_888 or [RGBA_8888](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PixelFormat.html#RGBA_8888).

Comment: Cool, thanks - that's sounds like it.  I'll check on Monday when I get back to work.  There seems to be a number of issues when using a surfaceview in a scrollview.  Black bars above and below when scrolling (I've hacked in negative margins to fix that).  Random black rectangles appearing (fixed with transparent background colour).  There also seems to be elastic band affect when scrolling as if the surfaceview can't keep up.

Comment: The SurfaceView window (position, size) is handled by the WindowManager, so e.g. putting a SurfaceView in a scrolling list is not a good idea.  TextureView will work properly.  If you really want the details, see https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html .

Comment: It works well.  I switched from the SurfaceView to the TextureView and that solved a lot of other issues. I have one issue remaining in that the ScrollView has a gradient from top to bottom (grey to white).  When I set the background colour to grey to try and match the ScrollView the top of the TextureView matches but the bottom doesn't because below is whiter.  Thanks for your help it's saved a lot of time.